# DYMO defaults to wrong label type

Tags: windows-8.1, printing

I have a DYMO 450 LabelWriter that I am using for a kiosk. When the driver first installs, the default paper type is set to 30325 Address. Well, I need it to default to 30323 Shipping.

I have rare circumstances where if power goes out or if windows decides to re-install the printer (as copy 1), the paper type gets set back to 30325 Address.

I have tried removing all forms from the print server, but they get re-added when the printer driver is installed. Is there a program/script that can set paper type for a printer on login or remove forms?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know of a generic way to set the paper type for all printers, but what you can do is set up all the printer driver options just the way you want, then export them to a file and re-import on login.

To store all printer settings into a file use:

```
printui /Ss /n "printer name" /a "file.dat"
```

To restore all printer settings from a file use:

```
printui /Sr /n "printer name" /a "file.dat"
```

If you're unsure of the exact printer name string, you can list the default printer and all installed printers using:

```
cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -g

cscript C:\Windows\System32\Printing_Admin_Scripts\en-US\prnmngr.vbs -l
```

Comment: This is clearly the right answer. Unfortunately, the DYMO does not have the paper type in its options. The solution for me is to get a printer that does have this.